How to persist MutationObserver after window.location change?
Lets say I am observing the document using MutationObserver:
let mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
...
});

mutationObserver.observe(document, {
    attributes: false,
    childList: true,
    characterData: false,
    subtree: true
});

After this, lets say I am loading a new URL using:
window.location = newUrl;


Is it expected behaviour that the previous MutationObserver will be destroyed?

Is there any way to persist MutationObserver after the URL changes?


If not, is there another approach I can use which persists MutationObserver?


Yes. 2. No. Everything gets unloaded. You need to create a new MutationObserver when the page loads. Another approach would be to use an SPA architecture, but this is not a trivial change to make to an existing site.


What is the reason for persisting the MutationObserver?

MutationObserver itself does not support persistence.
If you need to implement the functionality you want， maybe  you can try:

SPA.
using localstorage or indexdb, this code may be an idea

// create MutationObserver instance
const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
  // change handler insert data to localstorage
  mutations.forEach(mutation => {
    localStorage.setItem('mutationData', JSON.stringify(mutation));
  });
});


const targetNode = document.getElementById('target_id');
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
observer.observe(targetNode, config);

// url change handler. (use history.pushState，popstate...)
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
  // get localstorage data
  const savedMutationData = localStorage.getItem('mutationData');
  
  if (savedMutationData) {
    // Assuming you want to process these change data under a new URL, use this data based on your specific business needs
    const mutationObj = JSON.parse(savedMutationData);
    console.log('mutationObj:', mutationObj); 
  }
});

